# Can't pass a parameter to a asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Sold()
        {
            using (WipDBEntities db = new WipDBEntities())
            {
                ViewData.Model = db.GetSummaryProiect("Test").ToList();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This is working fine except that when i try to get the parameter from the url my view is empty

```
public ActionResult Sold(string PrjCode)
        {
            using (WipDBEntities db = new WipDBEntities())
            {
                ViewData.Model = db.GetSummaryProiect(PrjCode).ToList();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I'm new to mvc so probably i'm doing something wrong, can you help me ?

EDIT

I have a route to handle this

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                "Componente", // Route name
                "Componente/Sold/{PrjCode}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Componente", action = "Sold", PrjCode= "" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The url looks like `[hostname]/Componente/Sold/Test`

Comment: Is PrjCode empty OR your query from database returns nothing in case of ...Sold(string PrjCode)?

Comment: query from database returns nothing PrjCode  has the right value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you expecting that value to come from? If you are using the default route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, and your value is in the `{id}` placeholder then the parameter name on your action method needs to be `id`.

Comment: I'm looking with the debugger and the 'PrjCode' var actually has the value "test" but the ViewData.Model is empty.

Comment: In your question, you used the value of "Test", but in your comment you used "test", is the casing the same (a typo) or does one return values while the other does not?

Comment: it's a typo in my comment sorry, the casing is the same

Comment: Have you used the debugger and verified that the action method is being hit? There's a chance that you have a different route that is being used.

Comment: Yes it's going to the right action method but for some reason when i pass the param to the query as a var instead of a hard coded string it's not returning any values anymore.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any whitespace in your action method parameter?  Try trimming the value when you pass it in to see if that helps.

Comment: Seems that I was a passing a parameter that was't in the database anymore, i'm gonna mark your answer, sorry for the trouble.